# What is the classical Chinese meaning of 或?

Tags: classical-chinese

I am reading a text that uses the following phrase:

> 或謂鄭相曰

I understand it generally to mean that

> someone told to the prime minister of Zheng saying

However, I don't understand exactly what the character 或 means here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It means "someone" in this case.

From zdic:

> 某人，有的人

From Iciba:

> [书] （某人； 有的人） someone ； some people

Comment: Hi Joe. Thanks for the response and particularly for the reference to zdic. I had not seen this site before, but I will be referencing it a lot in the future. Thanks.

Comment: @fmz no problem!

Answer (score 1):

**或**,is frequently to be seen in classical Chinese with the meaning——*someone*,such usage is barely seen in modern chinese language.

> 而楼上人往来屑屑，或凭或立，不一状。————《山市》蒲松龄

**或**:

It is composed of "**口**" and "弌".
**口** resembles the city wall surrounding a city
**弌** means the first time in night a soldier patrol with a polearm.

> **弌**, **弍** and **弎** refer to first,second,third time of patrol

Some people think that **弌**  means that defend his land with polearm

> 或，邦也。从囗，从戈，以守一。一，地也。——《说文》

Taking the above into consideration, **或** can be understood as **defending one's country with weapons.**

It therefore means ***country*** and by derivation, ***someone***.

---

**EDIT:**

If you are interested in classical chinese,[《古代汉语词典》](http://www.amazon.cn/%E5%8F%A4%E4%BB%A3%E6%B1%89%E8%AF%AD%E8%AF%8D%E5%85%B8-%E9%99%88%E5%A4%8D%E5%8D%8E/dp/B0011F959A) is recommended. This book is of authoritativeness in china.

If you are interested in modern chinese,[《现代汉语词典》](http://www.amazon.cn/gp/product/B008JAF6HA/ref=s9_simh_gw_p14_d0_i4?pf_rd_m=A1AJ19PSB66TGU&pf_rd_s=center-2&pf_rd_r=1H1XTE29HH16YKFH4JMH&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=58223152&pf_rd_i=899254051)  ，This book is used for standardized 普通话,and also used by every students attending college entrance examination.

Comment: This is not completely correct. The character actually consists of what you said + 一. 一 probably refers to the primary resource one tries to protect which is one's land.

Comment: In fact I would recommend 《辭海》《辭源》《康熙字典》 and 《王力古漢語詞典》 instead of 《古代漢語詞典》. I'd say 《王力古漢語詞典》 is excellent!